# Estimating Google Cloud Run costs for Twitch Chatbot Client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run, irc, twitch-api

I am working on a Twitch Chatbot and am planning to deploy the chatbot client on Google Cloud Run.  I am planning to use the `NojeJS` API plainly because I am familiar with the language.

Before I do that I would like to understand how an IRC client would impact the cloud run bill.

I am not able to wrap my head around IRC client implementation. Can someone please help me understand how can I calculate/estimate pricing for my application.

Would also like to know if there are any other cheap recommended approach to implement this?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Let me know if the below suggestion worked or if you are looking for something else?

Comment: @RoopaM The below suggestion was helpful. I am going do some test runs on Cloud Run and see if I can get more accurate estimate before I push my application to production.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

'Cloud run' is a managed service that costs you just for the resources (CPU and Memory allocated) that you utilize, rounded up to the next 100 millisecond. There is a free tier for each of these resources. The sum of the resources listed in the price table will represent your final Cloud Run bill.

You may estimate the cost of using Cloud Run by using the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Another option would be `compute engine` but, If you are okay with maintaining infrastructure, you can consider using it.

Also look at [this article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-run-pricing/) and [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing) to check the pricing table